# Better than MSDOS batch files?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, scripting

Is there something better than using MSDOS in a bat file to run commmand line operations and copy files around.

I am running into the old chestnut "gotchas" with long file names etc - and for some reason the bat file wont pause - when I insert PAUSE in my script after running a command - it's just annoying.

Whats better out there?

Cheers folks.

BTW - Just looked at Powershell and looks like the network/sys admin has blocked Powershell on our PCs (nice).

Comment: Look up differences between .BAT and .CMD files. .BAT is the old one, .CMD fixes some annoyances.

Comment: ahh ok - never knew about that.

Comment: Also, if you're tired of hearing "use powershell" all over again, try these guys http://www.jpsoft.com/

Comment: you have to buy jpsoft - and I just need to get the job done, like now, can't be bothered going through finance etc, building a case for why we should buy this software.... - but thanks anyways...

Comment: Idigas: Batch files will be run by cmd. exe, regardless of extension. Vidar: Can you post some code that allegedly fails? pause usually pauses and when it doesn't something else might be awry. Your description isn't exactly helpful for debugging, though.

Comment: Blocked Powershell, but not bat files. That's strange. What version of Windows are you running?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Take a look at [PowerShell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973757.aspx)

Comment: LOL 6 powershell responses in 30s

Answer (score 6):

There are a few rules of thumb when working with bat files.

- Use setlocal endlocal to preserve your enviroment variables outside the script
- Use double quotes whenever you work with files to allow files with spaces in the name
- Use pushd/popd instead of cd to move between directories also works with UNC paths
- If you run another bat file use the call keyword before it or your script will transfer control the new bat file and never return to the original.

Example: **quicksql.bat**

@echo off
setlocal

if "%1"=="" goto USAGE
set server=%1
if "%2"=="" goto USAGE
set database=%2
if "%3"=="" goto USAGE
set script=%3

sqlcmd.exe -S %server% -d %database% -i "%script%"
goto EOF

:USAGE

echo %0 server database script

:EOF
endlocal

Answer (score 5):

Actually, answers referring to `VBScript` really mean [Windows Scripting Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k(VS.85).aspx):

> WSH is a language-independent scripting host for 32-bit Windows platforms. Microsoft provides both **Microsoft Visual Basic Script** and **Java Script** scripting engines with WSH. It serves as a controller of ActiveX scripting engines, just as Microsoft Internet Explorer does. Because the scripting host is not a full Internet browser, it has a smaller memory footprint than Internet Explorer; therefore, WSH is appropriate for performing simple, quick tasks. Scripts can be run directly from the desktop by double-clicking a script file, or from a command prompt. WSH provides a low-memory scripting host that is ideal for non-interactive scripting needs such as logon scripting, administrative scripting, and so on. WSH can be run from either the protected-mode Windows-based host (Wscript.exe), or the real-mode command shell-based host (Cscript.exe).

Any windows language (besides `vbs` and `js`) that has access to good old `COM` (`ActiveX`) can use the same scripting objects. `Python` is one example, and `.NET` with `P-Invoke` is another.

The [Script Center Script Repository](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/scripts/default.mspx?mfr=true) on *technet* contains many examples of `WSH` usage in system administration, most in `VBS`.

Answer (score 4):

VB Script in a plain .vbs file.

Comment: Ditto on the VBS - I have a nice batch of VBS scripts for my routine maintenance type stuff. I'm sure I'll eventually have to move to PowerShell, so I up-voted both. :)

Answer (score 3):

I routinely install [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) and friends on every Windows box I use. A lot of folks use cygwin for this, but I far prefer [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Install cygwin and use bash scripts, or install perl and use perl scripts, or install ant and use...... hmmm... I forget what you use there.  Oh wait... ant scripts

Answer (score 0):

see - [Windows Powershell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx) (formerly monad)

Answer (score 0):

Scripting PowerShell is supposed to be quite nice. I have never done it, though, and you if you intend to distribute the script, the script users will need PowerShell as well.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's new-hotness command line and scripting language is called [PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx). It fixes many of the gotchas of batch files.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ZTreeWin](http://www.ztree.com/html/ztreewin.htm), it's a powerful Win32 text-mode file/directory manager and can be run without having to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Also out of date is 4DOS. Mind the licensing.

Answer (score 0):

[Windows Scripting Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k(VS.85).aspx).

- You can use a variety of languages to
  implement such as VBScript, JScript,
  or Python (I think I've even seen
  Perl).
- You get full access to the
  language built-in libraries.
- You get
  richer API's than with the
  plain-ole-shell.
- WSH is included with
  all shipping versions of Windows.
- You
  can mix-and-match languages, reuse
  blocks, add new libraries, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Take Command is an option.  I use it and love it:

http://www.jpsoft.com/index.html

Provides a Real Windows Scripting Language

> 164 Built-in Commands
>  245
>   Functions
>  159 System Variables
>   Mature well tested code
>  Upwardly
>   compatible with CMD.EXE with literally
>   thousands of additions

Answer (score 0):

You might consider Tcl. You can get a single file executable named tclkit, and associate it with .tcl files. Tcl has very robust file handling commands, and you also have the option of displaying native windows to display progress, add file choosers and the like.

Tcl isn't everyone's cup of tea, but it is a very powerful scripting tool. And with tclkits, deployment is trivial since it's just a smallish single file executable.

Answer (score 0):

Learn about Python or Ruby, It does whatever Powershell, VBScript, Perl, PHP does and more ;)